# how to convert the webpage to xml document using java?

Tags: html, xml, dom, xhtml

The assumption is the webpage is coded with correct tags. How can I Convert it to the XML file? I think the most webpages can be viewed as dom tree...How can I convert it to XML file?

Comment: Isn't HTML a subset of XML? I think you need to give us some more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: the html page can be viewed as dom. or otherwise html page can be converted to dom. I want to convert next from dom to xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) reads HTML and presents it as a DOM. Once you have your HTML as a DOM you should be able to process it and write it out as XML.

To output a DOM, see the [example code here](http://www.javazoom.net/services/newsletter/xmlgeneration.html) and the XMLSerializer in particular.